# SQL MAX(column) With Additional Criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a single table, where I want to return a list of the MAX(id) GROUPed by another identifier.  However I have a third column that, when it meets a certain criteria, "trumps" rows that don't meet that criteria.

Probably easier to explain with an example.  Sample table has:

UniqueId (int)
GroupId (int)
IsPriority (bit)

Raw data:

```
UniqueId    GroupId    IsPriority
-----------------------------------
    1           1          F
    2           1          F
    3           1          F
    4           1          F
    5           1          F
    6           2          T
    7           2          T
    8           2          F
    9           2          F
   10           2          F
```

So, because no row in groupId 1 has IsPriority set, we return the highest UniqueId (5).  Since groupId 2 has rows with IsPriority set, we return the highest UniqueId with that value (7).

So output would be:

```
5
7
```

I can think of ways to brute force this, but I am looking to see if I can do this in a single query.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0f37f/1)

```
WITH T
     AS (SELECT *,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY GroupId 
                                    ORDER BY IsPriority DESC, UniqueId DESC ) AS RN
         FROM   YourTable)
SELECT UniqueId,
       GroupId,
       IsPriority
FROM   T
WHERE  RN = 1
```